# Profile based, toggleable JSON minifying with Java, Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

With Jackson, the annotation `@JsonProperty("a")` on a field would serialize its name as `a`. With Gson, this is to be done as `@SerializedName("a")`.

Annotating all serialized fields of a class and going with the default Jackson setting would result in a minified JSON response which is what we want to achieve.

This obviously obfuscates the response, so it would be great to make this optional. With non-Production profiles the minifying should be turned off, whilst the Production profile should use the minified version.

The application uses Spring Boot 2 (REST + Data) and Java 8, and currently serializing with Jackson but that can change. The build is done via Maven.

We can use either Spring or Maven profiles for this.

Speculations:

- Drop the annotations and configure Jackson / Gson with profile based beans. Unsure whether possible.
- Jackson Annotations are currently not used. I could throw in my own implementation from an external module, and switch between the dummy and real one based on profile, hoping mine won't be autoconfigured. Dirty and may not work.
- Duplicate the response entities, but this is ugly and hard to maintain.

Anyhow, the question is how to make JSON minifying configuration-based, toggleable.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I want to conditionally deserialise fields based on Spring @Profile and wondering whether the same solution could solve both problems?

Comment: @dan.jones Not yet, unfortunately, this is still a problem I am facing.

Comment: That's not really the purpose of this question. But you can create JSON views with Jackson. You can try to tell the controller which view to use by linking it to a profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The indentation is not a problem. Maybe my question is not clear. The issue is regarding minifying the field names. Non-prod, I'd like to have "someLongFieldName" : 1. With prod profile, "s":1.

You may use a placeholder. Use `@JsonProperty("${your.property}")` instead of `@JsonProperty("a")`. Spring boot will evaluate the expression and replace it with the appropriate String.

Comment: Is this an answer or a reaction to the comment you quoted?

Comment: Actually, the comment @Aron left was for clarifying his question. So, it´s is both.

Comment: I would strongly advice you not to do that for the reasons I mentionned in my answer. This will lead to big issues in terms of maintanability and usability for clients.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's you have dev and prod profiles. To disable JSON minifying for dev profile just add file **application-dev.properties** with config:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

or with Java config:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevJacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.indentOutput(true);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Comment: The indentation is not a problem. Maybe my question is not clear. The issue is regarding minifying the field names. Non-prod, I'd like to have `"someLongFieldName" : 1`. With prod profile, `"s":1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you need to do, but I think of it as a code smell.

Using different keys according to the environnement (in our case, dev and prod, but it can have more) makes your APIs different according to the environnement. However, the content is actually the same. So you'll have different response for the same request according to the deployed API's profile.

Any consumer of the APIs should then be aware of the true meaning of obfuscated keys. Even worse: they'll have to handle both the obfuscated and "normal" keys to be able to communicate with the API no matter what profile is has been deployed with.

It will also make testing and API doc generation (swagger etc) more difficult.

I would strongly suggest to stick to a well named key and using compression of response (gzip format for instance).